# What is the lpstr filter for folders?

Tags: c++, winapi, directory, dialog, lpstr

I am trying to open a dialog box where the user selects a certain folder on pure C++, no .Net framework or C#, and am struggling to find how the lpstr would filter everything but directories. I am currently using the OPENFILENAME function. I tried filtering to .dir, but it does not work. Anyone know the actual extension or any solutons?

Comment: Guessing you should tag this for winapi. The common file dialog box isn't really designed for selecting directories. Have a look at `SHBrowseForFolder` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OPENFILENAME` struct is used with the old [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getopenfilenamea) [Common Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/common-dialog-box-library), which can't be used to select a folder. It is simply not designed for that purpose.

You need to use [`SHBrowseForFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera) instead, or in Vista+ you can (*and should*) use the newer [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog) [Common Item Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/common-file-dialog) with the `FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using SHBrowseForFolder()
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shbrowseforfoldera